# Connection passing account to cUrl - Windows

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, curl, ftp

I have a few text files I need to ftp to a secure site. I am using windows command-line batch to put the curl statement (I have to pass account, username, and password) to the site to connect. I searched on how to put the account, but I was not lucky. Below is my command, I appreciate if you please correct me:

```
curl -k -T test.txt -u name:psw type=6 -F description=testfile https://srvr.test.com/file_import.php
```

Comment: Even though you're using batch, the question is about curl syntax, not batch. So, this is not a programming question and it should be asked at [su].

Comment: What happened when you tried what you wrote? Any errors? What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: I get file exceeded maximum size of 256MB even though the file is only 2k (test file)